# Get Force.com Domain from Apex

Tags: force.com-sites, custom-domain

I'm looking for a way to get the registered Force.com domain from Apex. At the moment I just want to check if there is a domain or not.

This is the domain you register once, when trying to create a public site.

I know you can find the subdomain for a site by querying the field `subdomain` in the object `Site`, however, it is possible that a domain is registered but a Site wasn't created. How can I figure out the force.com domain in that scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This currently isn't exposed in Apex.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it by using the getHeaders() method on PageReference class. I've not tested this, but thats where I'd start.

Expose a stupid simple (empty) visualforce page publically, and create a page reference to it. The getURL() method will return the relative url, but hte headers will  likely have the full url.

Let me know if it works.